# How can I, using Finder, enter an "app". Not open, enter

Tags: macos, finder, applications, navigation

Apps in macOS are not `.exe` files, they are folders with special rules, but folders.
I can, use <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and paste the path towards and past the app. But that is beyond inconvenient.

So, scenario: I am in Finder and I reach the app. I want to go past the app, into the underlying folder structure. What do I do?

Comment: "folders with special rules" The lingo for these is "bundles", btw

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Right click [or Ctrl/click]  > Show Package Contents

[image]